# How do i add custom headers for my nightwatch.js tests?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

So I been digging the web (google, stackoverflow, github) trying to find a simple way to add custom headers to my tests. So far nothing pop out. Maybe some thing for java or firefox, but nothing clear.

I'm using:

- NodeJS: v6.11.3
- Nightwatch: 0.9.16
- ChromeDriver: 2.32
- Selenium 3.5.3

So what i would like is that headers would propagate in all tests including 302 Redirects

```
before: {
  this.setHeaders = {
      "X-CUSTOM-HEADER-A": "Data-A",
      "X-CUSTOM-HEADER-B": "Data-B",
  }
}
```

Is there something like this avaliable? Any chromedriver args maybe?

Comment: Maybe try https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest. I know for  sure it's possible using a proxy and attaching that to the chrome capability.

Comment: For anyone with the same problem i ended up setting a local proxy with mitmproxy to inject headers. https://mitmproxy.org/ brew install mitmproxy

Answer (score 2):

The new Nightwatch 2.x release supports talking to CDP.  So for Chrome, you can use the following.  You have to call 'Network.enable' first to enable the Network dev commands. (This took a little trial-and-error.)

```
await browser.chrome.sendDevToolsCommand('Network.enable')
await browser.chrome.sendDevToolsCommand('Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders', 
    { 
        headers:
            {
                "X-CUSTOM-HEADER-A": "Data-A",
                "X-CUSTOM-HEADER-B": "Data-B"
            }
    })
```

More info on the dev tool commands in Nightwatch:
https://nightwatchjs.org/api/commands/#using-chrome-devtools-protocol